# How to disable Windows safe mode programmatically with PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, cmd, windows-10, registry

I have a script that I wrote that I am using to uninstall and re-install a program in our environment. This program is Bit9 (Carbon Black), and per their help desk, the only way to disable the service (so that I can uninstall and reinstall) is to boot into safe mode and disable the service their. I have written a PS script to take care of the majority of the heaving lifting, and a C# service to kick the script off in safe mode. The script is supposed to disable safe mode and then reboot back into regular mode, but I cannot get it to work. 
I've tried the following commands:

- `& C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
- `Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe' -ArgumentList "/deletevalue {current} safeboot" -Verb RunAs`
- `Invoke-Command -FilePath 'C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe' -ArgumentList "/deletevalue {current} safeboot" -Verb RunAs`
- I've even tried placing the command in a batch file and calling it from the script.

Nothing seems to be working. The most common error I am getting is:

```
This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
Start-Process : 
At C:\ta_fss\Bit9ForceInstall\bit9uninstall.ps1:255 char:13
+             Start-Process -FilePath $bcdedit -ArgumentList $deletePar ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this to work?

Thanks

EDIT: Seems like using `bcdedit.exe` in safe mode is not possible. So, next question: is there a registry setting to enable/disable safe mode? That might be better/ easier. I just can't seem to find it. Everything I've found online points to old versions of Windows using `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Option` which doesn't exist in Windows 10. Unless that needs to be added. Also not sure how to configure Windows to boot into Safe Mode with Networking.

Comment: How are you starting the script? It looks like you are just having issues with finding `bit9uninstall.ps1` alongside the script. Inside the script have it throw an error if `Test-Path "C:\ta_fss\Bit9ForceInstall\bit9uninstall.ps1"` is `$null`. Let me know if this isn't the issue, I would be surprised.

Comment: `bit9uninstall.ps1` is the name of the script that is running. The script is getting called and started fine as this error is coming from the log file generated from the script. All of the other lines of the script run fine. This is the only one that doesn't.

Comment: Sorry I misspoke, `Start-Process -FilePath $bcdedit -ArgumentList $deletePar` try doing `Test-Path $bcdedit`

Comment: Well, you're right. `Test-Path $bcdedit` comes back as false. Which makes no sense since it is a variable that is pointing to `C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe`. It has to be something to do with being in safe mode, but I have no idea how to get around it.

Comment: Run it for that path instead of `$bcdedit` and print out `$bcdedit`. What do both say?

Comment: After a bunch of testing and debugging, it seems as if Windows doesn't like bcdedit.exe being run from a script. Because once I started to push this out with our remote software (BigFix), I was getting the same error even just trying to enable safe mode. So  ended up writing a program in C# to enable/disable safe mode and used that instead. Seems to be working now.